# Jquery UI modal dialog will autoOpen but not click open

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, dialog

While it does seem this would have been asked a million times no matter of search phrasing seems to locate the exact issue. So, another question for the "pros". Opening a dialog is relatively easy, yes. I created a sample page to test the code and make sure it works, and it does. Then I added an alert() to the click event and whoa! its not recognizing the click but it will on the sample page. the click event...

```
$( "a#newDialog" ).click(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog('open');
    alert('Button Clicked');
    return false;
});
```

The difference between the sample page and the actual page is the link itself

```
<a name="node02" id="newDialog" href="#">OpenDialog</a>
```

What I've narrowed down is how the link arrives on the page. In the sample page it is static. In the real page it is included through an ajax call fetching a json file that has the markup for the link. So it has to be something to do with being unable to access the dialog functions. Is this correct? and how could I go about making this work? While we are at it I need to know how to get the `name="node2"` from the link and include it into the dialog for an ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your problem is that when you assign your click handler, the link doesn't exist so it doesn't "bind" to that link and is effectively useless. You need to use jquery 'on': https://api.jquery.com/on/

Let's assume your link is contained in a parent element #parentContainerId **that exists in the DOM when you assign your click handler**. In this case, you can use delegated events as described in the link above.

```
$( "#parentContainerId" ).on('click', 'a#newDialog', function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog('open');
    alert('Button Clicked');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Unbelievable, I even knew that! clearly the coffee has wore off and I now I must take a break. thanks for the help

Comment: Consider this - 
You: Wife! Make me coffee. 
(Wife is not home)
...

(Wife returns home)
You: Why didn't you make me coffee?
Wife: Guess I didn't get the message :)